# NS_ENUM as NSNumber with" @"

Tags: objective-c, enums

The following is true.

```
NSNumber *a= @90;
```

But, If I have NSInteger in a NS_ENUM and use "@" prefix it says "Unexpected '@' in a program"

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,Names){John=1};

NSNumber *a= @John;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `John` in parentheses:

```
NSNumber *a = @(John);
```

You must use parentheses with the `@` if the value isn't an actual number literal. And of course you can use the parentheses even if it is a number literal.

All valid:

```
NSNumber *a = @4;
NSNumber *a = @3.14;
NSNumber *a = @-6;
NSNumber *a = @(4);
NSNumber *a = @(4+5*3);
NSInteger magic = 42;
NSNumber *a = @(magic);
NSNumber *a = @([@"42" integerValue]);
```